# JS Reference Error on calling function from link

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

I've been working on JS for just under 6 months now, but today when I tried to start a new project, I couldn't get a simple function to run from a link... I've searched around, simplified my code and still can't get it.

I'm getting a reference error, saying 'test' is not defined. Not really sure why as it's worked perfectly every other time as far as I can remember.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascipt">

    function test()
    {
      alert("Entered");
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
  <p id="data"></p>
  <a onclick="test()" href="#">Fetch Data</a><br />
  <a href="javascript:test()">Fetch Data v2</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

At this point, I don't even know what to do...

Comment: `a href="javascript` and `a onclick="` Don't use inline handlers, attach them properly with Javascript instead if at all possible

Comment: Also, `type="text/javascipt"` Spelling matters in programming

Answer (score -1):

Remove the type="text/javascipt" from your script tag, or correct spelling.

Answer (score -1):

You have a spelling mistake with:

`text/javascipt` (should be `text/javascript`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function test()
    {
      alert("Entered");
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
  <p id="data"></p>
  <a onclick="test()" href="#">Fetch Data</a><br />
  <a href="#" onclick="test()">Fetch Data v2</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```